# Java script click counter: problems with origin policy?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a Javascript file that act as "click counter"?

What I want to do is that I put that Javascript file in my domain

```
mydomain.com/js/clickcounter.js
```

And anyone can include it to start counting clicks..

**Example for** `THEIRdomain.com/index.html`

```
 <script src="mydomain.com/js/clickcounter.js"></script>
```

And a possible script:

```
function myDomain_TrackClicks(){
    xhttp.open("POST", "mydomain.com/trackClicks.php", true);
    xhttp.send( "pagevisited=" + encodeURIComponent( window.location.href));
}

if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', myDomain_TrackClicks);
} else {
    if(window.onload) {
        var curronload = window.onload;
        var newonload = function(evt) {
            curronload(evt);
            myDomain_TrackClicks(evt);
        };
        window.onload = newonload;
    } else {
        window.onload = myDomain_TrackClicks;
    }
}
```

Or is that limited by some origin policy? Origin policy really confuses me.

Comment: Please comment if there are problems with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thats required is your server must respond with the correct HTTP headers when `mydomain.com/js/clickcounter.js` is requested by the browser.

Specifically, this header must be included in the response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This tells the browser that the resource may be requested from any origin.

Recommended reading - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS